# How to rotate the bracket index in a chemfig structure

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw a structure of a large molecule using chemfig, where the repeat unit is vertical. Is there a way to rotate the index of the bracket? In my attempt, it is rotated by 90 degrees and it is also on the left side; ideally it would be on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:0]=^[::0](-[::60])-[::300](=[::60]O)-[::-60]O-[@{op}::60]-[::300]-[::60]O-[@{cl}::300]H}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={()},height = 10pt, h align=false, rotate = 0, indice = 10]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of tackling this problem, but probably not much less hacky than CrocoDuck's answer, could be to place the index in a `\rotatebox` (credit for this idea goes to CrocoDuck) and shift it to the right using some `\hspace`. In order not to affect the parenthesis when shifting the index, a `\rlap` is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{[:0]=^[::0](-[::60])-[::300](=[::60]O)-[::-60]O-[@{op}::60]-[::300]-[::60]O-[@{cl}::300]H}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={()}, height=10pt, h align=false, rotate=-90, indice={\rotatebox{90}{\rlap{\hspace{2em}10}}}]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

chemfig always places the index "n" at the bottom of the delimiter.

I created an alternative, not very elegant, but functional.

But if you just want to rotate the index, use `index = \rotatebox{90}{10}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
        \chemfig{[:0]=^[::0](-[::60])-[::300](=[::60]O)-[::-60]O-[@{op}::60]-[::300]-[::60]O-[@{cl}::300]H-[:20,.7,,,,draw=none]\parbox{.5cm}{10}}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={()},height = 10pt, h align=false, rotate = -90,indice={}]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, nice idea, so you essentially add an invisible atom for the 10, right? Maybe, you can also use `\rotatebox` in combination with other boxes to align the index.

Comment: I tried using a combination of \rotatebox and \hspace to insert space and shift the number 10 to the position shown in the figure, but that shifted the delimiter as well.

Comment: I didn't know the \rlap command. My method has the advantage of using just \chenfig to get the same result.